# Creating nested directories

Tags: bash, command-line, directory, mkdir

I want to write a `bash` script that will get a command line argument and create nested directories under the user home directory. 
E.g `a/b/c`

```
mkdir -p $1/$2/$3
```

But I want create not just three levels of directories, I want get command line argument  3 or 5 and create necessary quantity of nested directories

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/sh

(
    IFS=/
    mkdir -p "$*"
)
```

The expansion of `"$*"` will be a single quoted string consisting of all arguments to the script concatenated together with the first character of `$IFS` as a delimiter.  This is why we also set `$IFS` to `/`.

I'm running that in a subshell to avoid setting `IFS` for the rest of the script (it changes the behavior of certain things, like how `read` works). If there's nothing else in the script, you can leave `(` and `)` out.

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
`-- script.sh

0 directory, 1 file
```

```
$ ./script.sh 1 2 3 4 {a..k}
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- 1
|   `-- 2
|       `-- 3
|           `-- 4
|               `-- a
|                   `-- b
|                       `-- c
|                           `-- d
|                               `-- e
|                                   `-- f
|                                       `-- g
|                                           `-- h
|                                               `-- i
|                                                   `-- j
|                                                       `-- k
`-- script.sh

15 directories, 1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the inter field separator `$IFS` to `/`, then `"$*"` will expand to `a/b/c/...`:

```
IFS=/
mkdir -p "$*"
```

Comment: this is the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580694/236063